# Couchapp - default template not found when running `couchapp generate ...` on Windows

Tags: couchapp

After thorough browsing I decided to post here as I could not find a working prompt on the problem.
I installed CouchDB and Couchapp (in version 1.0.0, freshest one on Github) on Win8 machine and when I try to run `couchapp generate app contacts` I get:

#### 2014-11-21 22:01:00 [ERROR] couchapp error: Can't create a CouchApp in C:\Users\

#### Michal\Desktop\contacts: default template not found.

I have not so far dug deeper into the Couchapp code to see if I can fix it. Fixes applied by Couchapp creator, Benoit, don't work for me.
All advice/constructive criticism much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it working - all that was needed was to include an environment variable for couchapp.exe. So, if you are installing a standalone version of Couchapp from the downloads section ( https://github.com/downloads/couchapp/couchapp/couchapp-1.0.0-win.zip, e.g. ) you NEED TO MAKE SURE that you first of all execute the installer and then point you environment variables Path to it, that's all. Hope it helps.